# How to show a badge number on a tabItem of a TabView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, tabview

I'm working on a side project with SwiftUI, and I have a scenario where I need to show a badge number on one of the `tabItems` of my `TabView`.

I have everything set with my models, and binding and so on. But I have been looking for 2 days now to find a `modifier` to show the badge, but unfortunately all my researches had faced a dead end.

I had went through Apple SwiftUI API Documentation for [TabView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) and searched here on stack overflow and also of course tons of google search results' links.

I'm observing an environment object which hold a list of items and I know how to bind the badge with my items count, so when I have any item update (added, deleted) the badge will be updated. But I'm unable to find a way to show the badge number itself on the `tabItem`.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: SwiftUI 3 (requiring iOS 15) now has a `.badge` modifier. [See this answer for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894115/77567)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no modifiers for setting badge number on tab item and If you try to add custom view for that, it won't be visible; This is from TabView documentation:

> Tab views only support tab items of type Text, Image, or an image
>   followed by text. Passing any other type of view results in a visible
>   but empty tab item.

So, I tried a workaround and it works.
Using ZStack with GeometryReader and some calculations to place the custom badge view in the right place.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var badgeNumber: Int = 3
  private var badgePosition: CGFloat = 3
  private var tabsCount: CGFloat = 3

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
        // TabView
        TabView {
          Text("First View")
            .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "1.circle")
              Text("First")
          }.tag(0)

          Text("Second View")
            .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "2.circle")
              Text("Second")
          }.tag(1)

          Text("Third View")
            .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "3.circle")
              Text("Third")
          }.tag(2)
        }

        // Badge View
        ZStack {
          Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)

          Text("\(self.badgeNumber)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(Font.system(size: 12))
        }
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        .offset(x: ( ( 2 * self.badgePosition) - 1 ) * ( geometry.size.width / ( 2 * self.tabsCount ) ), y: -30)
        .opacity(self.badgeNumber == 0 ? 0 : 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sample project available on github:
https://github.com/aelzohry/TabBarSwiftUI

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks! 
I had adjusted the badge appearance to fit my need.

Comment: You're welcome. That's the power of Views in SwiftUI; you can adjust them as you like to fit your needs.

Comment: This worked great until I added a text field to my view. When the keyboard opened and shifted the bottom of the view up, it brought the floating badge with it :/

Comment: Note that with iOS 14, you'll need to add .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) to the enclosing ZStack to avoid the keyboard floating badge issue.

Answer (score 11):

### iOS 15+

We can now use a native [`badge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyhstack/badge(_:)-7mq9z) modifier that is available in list rows and tab bars:

```
TabView {
    Text("Tab One")
        .tabItem {
            Text("Home")
            Image(systemName: "house")
        }
        .badge(3)
}
```